# Convert IAsyncResult pattern to Tasks

Tags: c#, .net

There are some older code that I am working with which uses the IAsyncResult pattern. There are already delegates defined for Begin- and End- operations. How should I refactor these to be Task based without worrying about the implementations for the delegates?

Example of current code:

```
this.CallAsync(
    (thisRef, t, c, s) => thisRef.SomeMethod(thisRef.targetHost, t, c, s),
    (thisRef, r) => thisRef.SomeMethod2(r));
```

where the definitions are as below:

```
void CallAsync(BeginCall beginCall, EndCall endCall) {
    // do some async operations with beginCall and endCall
}

delegate IAsyncResult BeginCall(T thisPtr, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, object state);
delegate void EndCall(T thisPtr, IAsyncResult r);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the safest bet would be to use the [TaskFactory.FromAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.fromasync?view=netframework-4.7.2) method. You need to pick the correct overload to fit your existing delegate definitions.